# Directshow, Stream Buffer Engine, IStreamBufferSink

Tags: directshow

using IStreamBufferSink in this way:

> IStreamBufferSink *pBufferSing = NULL;
>
> ...
>
> hr = pBufferSink->LockProfile(NULL);

where will the stub file be placed (it's location)?

Answer (score 0):

They are in the User's temp directory. In winXp:

C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temp\TempSBE